# Flagging post shows number in Queue but then Queue empty?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I just flagged an Answer as 'Not an Answer'. The system shows me that there is one item in the queue, but presents me with an empty queue as shown in the screen-shot.
[image]

My flags should not be present in the review queue, and the system should not warn me that there is something in the queue, if I can't vote on it.

Comment: There is a lag/delay in the system, mods experience the same. sometimes clearing your browser cache (or restarting the browser) clears this. Mods appreciate all community flagging.

Comment: @Mapperz: Is it just a lag, or does it go away because someone else deals with the review, and hence the item gets out of the review queue?

Comment: Devdatta, it's probably both. At least when I've seen similar things and check who's on now or the moderator edit changelog there's been activity in the last few minutes.